# Not able to fetch the clicked document from firebase firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i'm new to firebase and i'm trying to fetch the clicked element's ID so I can pass it to the delete method. The problem is that i'm getting all the IDs of the documents of the logged in user, and not only the clicked one.

here is what I've tried so far:

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('interventions')
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: user.uid);
    var querySnapshots = await collection.get();
    for (var snapshot in querySnapshots.docs) {
      var documentID = snapshot.id;
      print('clicked doc: $documentID');
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("interventions")
          .doc(documentID)
          .delete();
    }
  },
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.delete,
    color: Colors.white,
    size: 22,
  ))
```

can anyone help me out with it? I'm trying to only remove the clicked element and not all of the elements! thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you include source code of where the IconButton is attached

Comment: It's fixed, I loaded the data and extracted the id of the current index and it worked pretty fine! How can I close/answer this question btw?

Comment: @FedyBelaid: You can post an answer below and accept it. That's a common and encouraged practice on Stack Overflow, if you think the answer may be useful to others in the future. If you don't think that'd be useful, you can delete the question of vote to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I loaded the data and extracted all the elements using                 `QueryDocumentSnapshot x = snapshot.data!.docs[index];` then passed the ID of the current doc using x.id!